# UsernamePasswordAuthentication, WCF and Universal Apps (Windows 10)

Tags: c#, wcf, security, authentication, uwp

Does the UWP platform (Universal Windows - Windows 10) support connecting to a WCF service with username/password authentication?

If so, where is the documentation/walkthrough?

If not, how can we let Microsoft know that they need to do something about it?

I posted the original question on the MSDN forums here:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/15da2714-2707-4d07-8e4d-3c0f917387c1/uwpusernamepasswordauthentication-wcf-and-universal-apps-windows-10?forum=wpdevelop

Comment: The answer, straight from the horse's mouth is not yet.https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/15da2714-2707-4d07-8e4d-3c0f917387c1/uwpusernamepasswordauthentication-wcf-and-universal-apps-windows-10?forum=wpdevelop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, straight from the horse's mouth is not yet.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/15da2714-2707-4d07-8e4d-3c0f917387c1/uwpusernamepasswordauthentication-wcf-and-universal-apps-windows-10?forum=wpdevelop

I haven't heard anything about this since I originally posted this question. I've not heard anything about it since and also found that this was missing from other platforms like Android, and iOS. In the end, we opted for a different authentication where we grab an auth token and then every subsequent call requires the auth token to be sent across. This solution sits across all platforms and works well. It would have been nice is Microsoft had spent the time to get WCF perfect across all platforms and implemented the functionality on the new platforms, but it seems as though they will never do this considering WCF has fallen out of favour.